# Display NOT a title field in Entity Reference field but my own field

Tags: entities

By default 'Entity Reference' field uses 'Title' field to resolve Nodes.
Is there any good way to change that behavior so it use another field to do that?

What if I want to use URL field or my own custom field what should I do?

I just would like to know what are the good ways to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If by "resolve" you mean what is searchable in the entity reference autocomplete field, then yes you can change the entity selection mode in the fields settings from simple to view and create a custom view to populate options. There is a good step by step tutorial on how to do that here: http://www.jackrabbithanna.com/articles/creating-entity-reference-view